# Error while executing multiple lines in python interpreter

Tags: python, ubuntu, compiler-errors

I am experimenting with python and a good coding environment. Being an interpreted language I wanted to execute code line by line and understand what happens before I make a script. I tried running this simple code in the python interpreter. (I'm on ubuntu using python 2.7)

```
from time import localtime

print ('time is', localtime())
```

This executes perfectly well as a script. But when I try it on the interpreter :

```
>>> from time import localtime\
... print ('time is', localtime())
```

I get the following error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(localtime())
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I run it from the terminal:

```
$ python test.py
```

I get :

```
('time is', time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=19, tm_hour=20, tm_min=53, tm_sec=11, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=78, tm_isdst=1))
```

Edits:
**Second code:**

```
>>>import os

>>>print os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Comment: Why did you put a backslash at the end of the first line?

Comment: I used it to execute multiple lines. Is that not required? Like can I execute import statement, then execute the print statement?

Comment: Do you get the same error?

Comment: I tried this other piece of code as well. Pls check the edits

Comment: You don't need the backslash to execute multiple statements. The backslash is for splitting a single statement over multiple lines. Each statement should be on its own line, with no backslash escaping the newline.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138493/discussion-between-user10678-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

> This error comes when you append this line
>   os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**)) in python interactive shell.
>
> Python Shell doesn't detect current file path in **file** and it's
>   related to your filepath in which you added this line
>
> So you should write this line os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**))
>   in file.py. and then run python file.py, It works because it takes
>   your filepath.
>   That's the answer to the second question.

First question is fairly simple you forgot parentheses print( localtime()  )

```
>>> from time import localtime
>>> print ('time is ',localtime())
time is  time.struct_time(tm_year=2017, tm_mon=3, tm_mday=20, tm_hour=4, tm_min=32, tm_sec=55, tm_wday=0, tm_yday=79, tm_isdst=0)
>>>
```